# gstreamer - How to reduce streaming delay?

Tags: streaming, real-time, gstreamer

I am developing a video chat application and I need realtime streaming with audio and video in sync. This is what I did......

1. video encoding with x264 encoder and decoding
2. audio encoding with lamemp3 encoder and decoding
3. mpegts muxing and demuxing

**my sender command:**

`gst-launch-1.0 -e mpegtsmux name="muxer" ! udpsink host=172.20.4.19 port=5000 v4l2src ! video/x-raw, width=640,height=480 ! x264enc tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true ! muxer. pulsesrc ! audioconvert ! lamemp3enc target=1 bitrate=64 cbr=true ! muxer. rtph264pay`

**my reciever command:**

`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! decodebin name=dec ! queue ! autovideosink dec. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink`

However I am getting a delay of more than 1 second. What is causing this delay (assuming that I did something enherintly wrong)? And how would I minimize it?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865653/gstreamer-aac-audio-stream-delay-in-ios) question? It seems to have the same issue.