# GStreamer AAC audio stream delay in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, gstreamer, audio-streaming, live-streaming

I'm playing **aac audio stream** on my iOS device using GStreamer SDK, its working fine, but delay is above 2.0 seconds.

Can I make this delay lower then 2.0 seconds?

There may be some buffering issue.

This is how I'm creating the pipeline

```
pipeline = gst_parse_launch("playbin2", &error);
```

Comment: can you show more of your pipeline?

Comment: I'm following GStreamer iOS tutorial 5.

Comment: What streaming protocol is used here?

Also use GStreamer 1.x, the 0.10 version is outdated and unmaintained since years. You can find 1.x binaries at the official website: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/ (http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/1.6.0/)

Answer (score 0):

try setting the latency like this:

```
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(pipeline.source), "latency", 250, NULL);
```

Comment: Thansk, I'm beginner so can you let me now what is "source", Because there is no member named "source" in "struct_GstElement".

Comment: This is how i'm setting, g_object_set(pipeline, "uri", char_uri, NULL).